# Symfony : error while accessing an array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony1

i want to output an array containing numbers.

I'm creating the array like this (it recieved the statistics for the last 7 days) :

```
   <?php  public function getStatisticsTeams()
 {
  $tab = array();
  for($i=7;$i=0;$i--)
     {
   $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
   ->from('stJob j')
   ->where('j.created_at = ?', date('Y-m-d h:i:s' , time() - 86400 * $i ))
    ->execute()
   ->count();
   $tab[] = $q;
     }
   return $tab;
 }
```

action.class.php

```
$this->st_job = Doctrine::getTable('StJob')->getStatisticsTeams();
```

Use of the array in my template.php :

```
$chart->inlineGraph(array('hits' => $st_job), array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday' ....), 'div_id');
```

When i try to access to my array **it fails** because the function i use must have an array which is supposed to contain for example (43,5,87,3,29,8,10) , and when i `var_dump($st_job)` (my array)

```
object(sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator)#363 (3) { ["count":"sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator":private]=>  int(0) ["value":protected]=>  array(0) { } ["escapingMethod":protected]=>  string(16) "esc_specialchars" }
```

Do you have any idea of what i'm doing wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, symfony is set to automatically apply escaping strategies to the data you pass from your controllers to your views. You can either remove the setting, which is not recommended, or use:

```
$original_array = $sf_data->getRaw('st_job');
```